# symfony domcrawler parsing not working

Tags: php, symfony, web-crawler, html-parsing, domparser

i would like to grab multiple of values from the following html:

```
<div class="video">
    <a href="https://example.com/23422" class="hRotator">
        <div class="thumb_container" data-previewvideo="http://example.com/vid.mp4">
            <img src="http://example.com/thumb.jpg" class="thumb" alt="">
            <img class="hSprite" src="https://example.com/spacer.gif" sprite="https://example.com/23422.jpg" id="23422">
            <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="" poster="https://example.com/poster.jpg" src="https://example.com/23422.mp4"></video>
        </div>

</div>
</a>
</div>
```

I'm using symfony domparser but dont seem to get it right

```
  $crawler->filter('div .videoList')->first()->filter('div .video')->each(function($video) {

            $link = $video->filter("a");
             $href = $link->attr("href");
             $thumb_container = $link->filter("div .thumb_container");
              $preview_video = $thumb_container->attr("data-previewvideo");
              $thumbnail_image = $thumb_container->filter("img .thumb")->attr("src");
              $hSprite = $thumb_container->filter("img .hSprite")->first();
               $image_sprite = $hSprite->attr("sprite");
               $id = $hSprite->attr("id");
}
```

How i should parse the html?

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: it shows the whole output rather than the actual values. i wonder what i am doing wrong